# Is it possible (and how) to execute a program on the client machine from a web app? - Angular 5

Tags: angular, web, client-side

I'm developing a web app to replace an old application used as a monitoring app. The old app I'm copying has a little button that says "watch", and it invokes a program on the PC, similar to something like TeamViewer, but it only lets you watch, without the other end noticing.

So, what i want to do is, execute a program from my web-app, passing certain parameters to the app (it has to be able to spectate different machines), and the app needs to keep running. Obviously, there has to be some sort of security-issue to have this done. This app will be running only in LAN, between computers that don't have internet access to the outer world.

Is there any way I can invoke the program from the app-web running in a web browser? The only thing i found that kind of made what i want is [this link (weblogs.asp.net)](https://weblogs.asp.net/morteza/How-to-run-a-desktop-application-from-a-web-page), but it needs to have created a custom URL protocol in the machine before-hand. While this is not catastrophic, I'd rather have something that can be used from any machine in the LAN, without some sort of "preparation" in the machine.

One example of something that could be kind-of-related are magnet links for torrents. When you click in a magnet link, it asks you if you want to execute X application in your PC (your default torrent app), and you can agree or disagree (I have no problem with a security-check before executing the local program).

In case this is important, I'm developing the app using Angular 5 mostly (and a little back-end made with flask in python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so, in case someone finds this question and wants to do something similar to what I needed, here's what I ended up doing.

Use ElectronJS and create a .exe desktop version of my app, where I have access to the Electron API, from where you can exec files, and command lines.

It seems like it is not possible to execute files from the web browser, unless you use Internet Explorer, and set the webpage as trusted. With this, you can use an `ActiveXObject`, but using IE wasn't an option for me (or to anyone, probably. It's 2018, come on).